# Reference class libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class-library

A class library named `KMS` is referenced to another class library named `KMS_.Data` in my project. Following is code from `KMS.csproj` XML file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\KMS_.Data\KMS_.Data.csproj">
      <Project>{90d7da7b-689c-477a-b4eb-00df1f526fa3}</Project>
      <Name>KMS_.Data</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Despite this reference exists between the 2 class libraries, `KMS.Models` cannot be visible by files inside `KMS_.Data` class library, for totally unknown reasons. Since this reference exists in `KMS.csproj` file, I can refer files in `KMS_.Data` to files in `KMS` class library but can't do the opposite. Why so? I always thought it worked both ways and not just one. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u reference a class library A to a class library B, only A can access files in B and not the vice versa. Another poor design belonging to microsoft.